# What will happen if I delete the blockfile_xxxxxx on the peer or orderer node?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I setup a fabric network with 3 peer orgs and 1 orderer org on my local environment. I am curious about that what will happen if I modify/delete the blockchain_xxxxxx file on the peer or orderer node manually?

Is the any mechanism to sync the blockfiles among the peer nodes and orderer nodes?

I also had tried to delete these files and then sent a chaincode invoke request by the sdk. The application still worked even without these files..

So for the production env:
1. Can the blockfile_xxxxxx on the peer node be deleted?
2. Can the blockfile_xxxxxx on the orderer node be deleted?
3. If there are multiple orderer nodes, will the blockfiles being synced among the orderers?

Comment: I think it works because fabric updates the couchdb successfully but failed to append the blockfiles..

Comment: As far as I know, the peer will fail to work. You have to re-spawn the peer from scratch. Why do you want to do something like this?

Comment: @arnabkaycee Thanks.  Just want to know the impact when some peer or order admin delete the file carelessly... Does the 're-spawn' mean copy the block files form other peers?

Comment: Also, if one of the peer or the orderer get hacked and all the files are deleted, do we still have chance to recovery it?

Comment: Respawn means start peer from scratch and join the channel.Data will be gossiped to the peer to bring it back in sync.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) .

Comment: Maybe you can hit the upvote button.